# Centering ToC title with latex package tocloft

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

In my LaTex paper, I need to produce such a table of contents, list of figures and list of tables, all of which have the title being centered and capitalized, and other special additions (such as inserting lines with words "Chapters", "Figure", and "Table"). My elaborations on this project so far produced this latex code (see below).

However, the only thing that does not work for me is centering the title of the table of contents, which is labelled as one word "Contents." See the picture of the pdf output file below. What should I fix in my code? For my manipulations I used two packages: `titlesec` and `tocloft`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
% Set the page margins as required
\usepackage[left=1.25in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}     % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing % Double space 
\usepackage{endnotes}     % All notes 2b place at a separate section 'Endnotes'
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{acro}         % Acronyms/abbreviations
\include{00-Acronyms}     % List of acronyms, 2b updated
%--> acro manual: https://mirror2.sandyriver.net/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/acro/acro-manual.pdf
% Managing sections
\usepackage{titlesec}     % To modify the section titles
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}} % CHAPTER 1 [New Line] TITLE
\titleformat{\section}[display]            % each chapter has two lines...
  {\normalfont\Large\filcenter}{\MakeUppercase{Chapter~\thesection}}{0pt}{}
% Capitalizing the titles of the respective sections:
\renewcommand{\notesname}{\centering \MakeUppercase{Endnotes}}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centering \MakeUppercase{Contents}}
\renewcommand{\refname}{\centering \MakeUppercase{References}}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\centering \MakeUppercase{List of Illustrations}}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\centering \MakeUppercase{List of Tables}}
\usepackage{tocloft}      % <-- ...to modify ToC, LoF, and LoT
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large} % ToC = Table of Contents
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\Large} % LoF = List of Figures
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hfill\Large} % LoT = List of Tables
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hfill}
\usepackage{natbib}       % Bibliography management
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
% My info
\date{October 14th, 2023}

% ----- Start of the document --------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
% All notes to be in the separate section 'Endnotes'
\let\footnote=\endnote

% Table of Contents + making TOC not in bold font
{\let\bfseries\mdseries \tableofcontents} \newpage

% List of Figures/Illustrations
\listoffigures 
\addtocontents{lof}{{~Figure}~\hfill{Page}\par} % <- inserting a line w/"Figure"
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\uppercase{List of Illustrations}}
\newpage

% List of Tables
\listoftables
\addtocontents{lot}{{~Table}~\hfill{Page}\par} % <- inserting a line w/ "Table"
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\uppercase{List of Tables}}
\newpage 

% List of Acronyms/Abbreviations
\printacronyms[pages = {display=all,seq/use=false},
           name  = \uppercase{List of Acronyms}]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\uppercase{List of Acronyms}}

%
% ... some latex code
%

\end{document}
% ----- End of the document ----------------------------------------------------
```

[image]

Comment: Use `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} `

Comment: @SimonDispa thanks very much! It works.

Comment: You can add it as an answer to your question to help other readers. (And accept the answer yourself)

Comment: Like this? See below @SimonDispa

Comment: x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/77325346/2777074

Comment: If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every question. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my question was to change this line of the code above:

```
 \usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
```

And it works just fine!